# What is, "performing streamed install"

Tags: android, adb

I am running a build through adb command,

```
adb install myapp.apk
```

In the console, I get the message, Performing streamed install

What does this mean.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`PackageManager` has 2 CLI interfaces - legacy `pm` and new `cmd package`.

The legacy installation process required uploading the .apk file to `/data/local/tmp` folder first. The new process has the (default) option of using [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) instead of the temporary file. This option is called *Streamed Install*.

Comment: Can you briefly explain what do you mean by "using pipes"?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the previously installed application and caused the cache to be unable to continue.
I have tried many ways and the simplest way to fix it is to restart your phone or virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

in my case, This error shows when my virtual device storage is full.
I created a new virtual device again and the problem was solved.